# how to find the last format date of any drive in windows

Tags: windows, format

how to find the last format date of any drive(without c drive) in windows?
is it possible to know last formated date of any drive. In my case it is D Drive.

Comment: NTFS? FAT32? ReFS?

Comment: @Anders NTFS (64 bit windows)

Comment: There are open source NTFS implementations, take a look at their root structures and see if you can find a filetime property. If not, some of the $ special files creation dates might work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Anders I will try as per your suggestion.